# Debugging PL/SQL Collections using PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

How can I see in the debug window (PL/SQL Developer, version 10.0.5.1710) to look up information on an array of data in a collection: the nesting hierarchy, elements with data types and their values **without listing all its elements separately**?

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE T_userinfo IS RECORD(
        surname VARCHAR2(8),
        name    VARCHAR2(6),
        sex     VARCHAR2(6)
    );
    TYPE T_group_tab IS TABLE OF T_userinfo INDEX BY VARCHAR2(6);
    TYPE T_class_tab IS TABLE OF T_group_tab INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    team_tab T_class_tab;
BEGIN
    team_tab(0)('group1').surname := 'Bradley';
    team_tab(0)('group1').name    := 'Brian';
    team_tab(0)('group1').sex     := 'male';

    team_tab(1)('group2').surname := 'Johnston';
    team_tab(1)('group2').name    := 'Hilary';
    team_tab(1)('group2').sex     := 'female';
END;
```

I want to see in the debug window something like that:

```
0 => 
    'group1' => 
        'surname' => VARCHAR2 'Bradley'
        'name'    => VARCHAR2 'Brian'
        'sex'     => VARCHAR2 'male'
1 => 
    'group2' => 
        'surname' => VARCHAR2 'Johnston'
        'name'    => VARCHAR2 'Hilary'
        'sex'     => VARCHAR2 'female'
```

[Debugging PL/SQL Collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2faF8.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not possible at the moment. According to the [newest user guide I found on the web](https://origin2.componentsource.com/sites/default/files/resources/allround-automations/533856/manual.pdf) (page 25), PLSQL developer can show collection of scalar type on hovering mouse on variable or rightclicking and choosing *View collection variable* from context menu.

It is also possible to hover mouse on variable of record type to show values of record fields or even send these values into watch window:

```
team_tab T_class_tab;
team_tab0 T_group_tab;
team_tab0g T_userinfo;
...
team_tab(0)('group1').surname := 'Bradley';
team_tab(0)('group1').name    := 'Brian';
team_tab(0)('group1').sex     := 'male';
team_tab0 := team_tab(0);
team_tab0g := team_tab0('group1'); -- hover on team_tab0g
```

For complex types you have to make up custom function to dump data in format you require.